# Function objects created using Function.prototype.bind

Tags: javascript

https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-function.prototype.bind:

I can't understand the notes:

> Note 1
>
> [Function objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#function-object) created using `Function.prototype.bind` are [exotic objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#exotic-object). They also do not have a "prototype" property.
>
> Note 2
>
> If Target is either an arrow function or a [bound function exotic object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#bound-function-exotic-object), then the thisArg passed to this method will not be used by subsequent calls to F.

Can someone give some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding Note 1:

```
const bound = (function(){}).bind();
console.log(bound instanceof Function);
console.log(!("prototype" in bound));
// being an "exotic object" just means that it behaves unusual - in this case,
// having a special [[call]] operation
```

Regarding Note 2:

```
function example() { "use strict"; console.log(this); }
const bound = example.bind("Hello");
const boundAgain = bound.bind("World");
console.log(bound(), boundAgain()); // Hello Hello

function makeArrow() { "use strict"; return () => console.log(this); }
const arrow = makeArrow.call("Hello");
const boundArrow = bound.bind("World");
console.log(arrow(), boundArrow()); // Hello Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Note 1: Bound functions do not have prototypes

```
const target = { foo: "bar" };
const f = function() {};
const bound = f.bind(target);
console.log("f.prototype", f.prototype);
console.log("bound.prototype", bound.prototype);

VM439:4 f.prototype {constructor: ƒ}
VM439:5 bound.prototype undefined
```

Note 2: Arrow functions cannot be bound

```
const target = { foo: "bar", toString: function() { return "foobar"; } };
const normal = function() { return this; };
const arrow = () => { return this; };
const boundNormal = normal.bind(target);
const boundArrow = arrow.bind(target);
console.log("normal()", normal());
console.log("boundNormal()", boundNormal());
console.log("arrow()", arrow());
console.log("boundArrow()", boundArrow());
console.log("normal.call(target)", normal.call(target));
console.log("arrow.call(target)", arrow.call(target));

normal() Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
boundNormal() {foo: "bar", toString: ƒ}
arrow() Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
boundArrow() Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
normal.call(target) {foo: "bar", toString: ƒ}
arrow.call(target) Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
```

Comment: Arrow function can be bound (creatiing the `boundArrow` in your example), but they of course ignore the bound `this` argument as they still use lexical scoping.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it depends what you mean by "bound." If it doesn't behave any differently, I wouldn't consider it "bound." But yes, you can call bind() on it (as seen in my example)!